# Can I make HttpCallout from JS button ?

Tags: custom-button, webservices

Getting the below error, making callout from javascript button, referring a non-static method from a static one, which a valid one.How to avoid this?

Is calling a web service method from js button on detail page synchronous o  asynchronous.

In case it's asynchronous, how can we define the @future on something which is already asynchronous?

[image]

Comment: Please always include code and error messages as text, not images.

Comment: What are you doing with this button? Maybe it would be better to use the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm) directly?

Comment: just wanted to check if calling the method from js is async or sync.. if it's an async then we are able to @future on that because it's already async. I have written the code below on button and it seems it's async..sforce.apex.execute('JavaScriptButton','UpdateContact',{},{ onSuccess: function(result) {setTimeout(function(){ alert("callback")}, 5000)}, onFailure: function (error){} } );  I am able to edit the record in those 5 sec .

Comment: @sfdcfox per adrian comment below it's synchronous unless it's a future, batch, etc, however, there is callback function and I am able to edit the record between clicking the button and callback comes back.It seems to be asynchronous then. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @amidstCloud not to be confusing, but it's synchronous Apex Code and asynchronous JavaScript code. If you want/need to call a future method, I'm pretty sure that would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You send the request from your instance:

```
httpObj.send(reqObj);
```

What you tried to compile is a static call from the `Http` class. Also note there is virtually zero reason to ever cache this instance. Just use `new Http().send(someRequest)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am an idiot. Could You please help me with other question? Is calling this function from js button on detail page going to be sync or async?

Comment: Please do not ask follow up questions in the comments. That said all apex code is synchronous unless it's a future, batch, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @adrian. I will keep a note, though it wasn't a follow up it was a part of the main question.Thanks again for help. I have tried the code below code and it seems calling a apex method from js button is async  call back comes in 5 second and I am able to edit the contact record in between.......sforce.apex.execute('JavaScriptButton','UpdateContact',{},{
    onSuccess: function(result) {setTimeout(function(){ alert("callback")}, 5000)},
    onFailure: function (error){}
}
);  please correct me if I am missing something

Comment: C'mon man don't post code in comments. Update your original post to include any code you left out.